# Typo in Implementation Examples in Microsoft's "C# Language Specification for Asynchronous Functions"?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm reading Microsoft's [C# Language Specification for Asynchronous Functions](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23753), and it includes several *Implementation Examples* at the end, all of which have code like this:

```
var x = await e;
```

expands to:

```
$resume = delegate {
    ....
    $a1 = (e).GetAwaiter();
    ...
    if ($a1.IsCompleted)   // <-- questionable line
    {
        $a1.OnCompleted($resume))
        return;
    }
    ...
};
```

It seems like there is a typo there!  Shouldn't the `if` test be negated?  i.e.:

```
if (!$a1.IsCompleted)
```

Comment: There is a "connect" area or the async stuff; I think that would be a better plae for this discussion, since it is not RTM (and so time-localized). Hmm can't find it now though.

Comment: Yes, it is explicit in the text, "Evaluation of await expressions" section.  Quote: "If the result is false then ..The expression (a).OnCompleted(r) is evaluated".

Comment: It is a Word document, you can edit it :)